# Preventing a search if the default value is in place

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I have a site set up using WordPress and the following snippet of code:

```
<form id="searchform" method="get" action="<?php bloginfo('siteurl')?>/">
  <input type="text" name="s" id="s" onfocus="if (this.value == 'Search') {this.value = '';}" onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = 'Search';}"class="textbox" value="Search" />
</form>
```

How can I prevent a search taking place if the default string of 'Search' is being displayed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest you to use `placeholder`:

```
<input type="text" name="s" id="s" class="textbox" placeholder="Search" />
```

See this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2C97m/) to check how it works. It will display hint for user until he enter something. Of course, value of input with `placeholder` is still empty until user interaction.

Answer (score 1):

Not a direct answer, but…

Cant' you just use the `placeholder` attribute instead of that old method to replace the input value?

See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input#attr-placeholder

```
<input type="text" name="s" id="s" placeholder="Search" class="textbox" value="" />
```

Answer (score 0):

a `placeholder` would be better but you can `return` `false` `onsubmit` if the value is 'Search'.

```
<form id="searchform" method="get" action="<?php bloginfo('siteurl')?>" onsubmit="if(document.getElementById('s').value == 'Search'){return false;}/">
   <input type="text" name="s" id="s" onfocus="if (this.value == 'Search') {this.value = '';}" onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = 'Search';}"class="textbox" value="Search" />
</form>
```

Comment: I did try this method but got the following error:

Oops! Google Chrome could not find <site-url> onsubmit=

Comment: missed the closing " on action="<?php bloginfo('siteurl')?>